# Dynamic vs Static Nature of Input and Output String Streams

Tags: c++, iostream

`Rogue Wave Standard C++ Library Iostreams and Locale User’s Guide` mentions the following:

> As with file streams, there are three class templates that implement
> string streams: basic_istringstream <charT,traits,Allocator>,
> basic_ostringstream <charT,traits,Allocator>, and basic_stringstream
> <charT,traits,Allocator> … For convenience, there are the regular
> typedefs istringstream, ostringstream, and stringstream…

and

> Output string streams are dynamic. The internal buffer is allocated
> once an output string stream is constructed. The buffer is
> automatically extended during insertion each time the internal buffer
> is full.
>
> Input string streams are always static. You can extract as many items
> as are available in the string you provided the string stream.

Now if output string streams are dynamic and input string streams are always static, how do we reconcile between the two and realize the (input/ouput) stringstream?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reconcile" here? And why are you concerned with this documented behaviour? Unless you're targeting a low-resource environment where hidden dynamic buffers might cause issues this isn't anything worth worrying about.

Comment: The passage you cite is either incorrect for, or inapplicable to, `std::stringstream`. You can write to it (expanding the buffer), and read what you've just wrote (thus read beyond the string originally passed in). [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ke4qdc1Yj). It's also possible that "string you provided the string stream" means something else than "string passed to `stringstream`'s constructor or `str()` member"; I'm frankly not sure what "provided" is supposed to mean here, exactly.